# ExtJS: Custom ComboBox

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm just trying to create a custom ComboBox to reduce some boilerplate:

```
Ext.define('App.AutoComboBox', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    alias: 'widget.autocombobox',

    states: null,

    initComponent: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        if (!this.states) {
            this.queryMode = 'remote';
        } else {
            this.queryMode = 'local';
            this.bindStore(Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                type: 'array',
                fields: ['_placeholder_'],
                data: _.map(this.states, function(state) {
                    return {_placeholder_ : state}; })
            }));
            this.displayField = this.valueField = '_placeholder_'
        }
        this.validator =  function(v) {
            var field = this.displayField,
                index = this.getStore().findExact(field, v);
            return (index!==-1) ? true : 'Invalid selection';
        };
    },
    listeners: {
        select: function(combo, records) {
            console.log(combo.getStore().indexOf(records[0])); // !== -1
        }
    }
});
```

So that I can use it like:

```
requires: ['App.AutoComboBox'],
...
items: [{
    xtype: 'autocombobox',
    name: 'test_local',
    fieldLabel: 'test_local',
    states: [ 'cat', 'dog' ]  // local
}, {
    xtype: 'autocombobox',
    name: 'test_remote',
    fieldLabel: 'test_remote',
    store: 'Chipmunks', // a remote store
    displayField: 'chipmunk_name'
}]
...
```

But something is amiss. The `AutoComboBox` renders OK, shows dropdown of records fine, but when I *select* an item from the dropdown, the combobox's display field is not set. The store seems to find the selected record (as seen by the `select` listener), but the value is still not set...

Help? thanks.

**Edit:** FIXED by moving `this.callParent(arguments)` *after* the new store is bound. Now accepting answers that explain *why* this fixes it... (I don't know why it works.. but it does)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the parent [`initComponent`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/source/ComboBox.html#Ext-form-field-ComboBox-method-initComponent) method, the `displayField` is used to create the `displayTpl`:

```
    if (!me.displayTpl) {
        me.displayTpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
            '<tpl for=".">' +
                '{[typeof values === "string" ? values : values["' + me.displayField + '"]]}' +
                '<tpl if="xindex < xcount">' + me.delimiter + '</tpl>' +
            '</tpl>'
        );
    } else if (Ext.isString(me.displayTpl)) {
        me.displayTpl = new Ext.XTemplate(me.displayTpl);
    }
```

The `bindStore` call has probably nothing to do with it, I believe that this is this line that must be put before the call to the parent method:

```
this.displayField = this.valueField = '_placeholder_';
```

Comment: Ah you are indeed correct! Thanks for your time rixo! Much appreciated!